# Filling an empty list with a previously unknown number of elements in Python

Tags: python, list

I want to slice a bigger document that is separated by a particular phrase into parts and then save those parts separately. ( a list of list was the goal)

My problem is when I start with an empty list, I don't know how many elements are in there in advance. Also  cannot create a placeholder element in it , since I have to index that again I think ( again gives me out of range error)

```
f = open(PATENTS, 'r')
text =f.read()
counter=0
textblock=[]
textblocklist=[]
stext= text.splitlines()

for line in stext:
    if line !='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>':

        textblocklist.append(line)

    else:
        counter+=1
        textblock.append(textblocklist)
        textblocklist=[]

f.close()

for n in textblock:
    with open('file_{0}.dat'.format(n),'w') as ffile:
        ffile.write(textblock[n])
        ffile.close()
```

I simply don't know how to achieve this. I want a list (textblock) that contains a number of elements ( the number is calculated in counter). Each element is a list of lines I guess, that are divided by the phrase in the if statement. Can anyone help me?

Comment: So what happens? What should happen instead? It looks like you're filling `textblock` with references to the same `textblocklist` - add `textblocklist = []` after `textblock.append(...)` to fix that

Comment: can you provide sample input and its output ?

Comment: sorry it seems i cannot even express what i want. I have a big document.  i want it divided whenever the phrase in the if statement comes. Then i want that lies between it( the lines of text) saved in a list. The list has a number of elementes equal to counter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should reset textblocklist when you find a delimiter.

```
for line in stext:
    if line !='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>':
    textblocklist.append(line)

    else:
        counter+=1
        textblock.append(textblocklist)
        textblocklist=[]
```

Comment: i thought it was  "for lines in " and then .append(lines) ?

Comment: @StephanKetterer: If you are asking why I remove the plural from your variable name, it is because inside the for loop, the variable is first equal to line1, then to line2 etc. : it is always a single line

Comment: i am sure that question seemed funny to you :) but i am really asking such dumb beginner questions :(

Comment: @StephanKetterer: Your question was fine. You can call that variable anything you like, but it's more sensible to give it a singular name because, as Eric said, it holds one line at a time. FWIW, there are ways to make your program a little more efficient, but unless the PATENTS file is huge your current approach (as modified by Eric) is ok.

Comment: Yes, asking simple questions is fine. But I wasn't entirely sure what you mean.